# How make QML ListView not flickable?

Tags: qt, listview, qml, qt-quick

I was wondering if there's any way for `ListView` to behave like a desktop control and not react with scrolling to mouse dragging?

I know about the `interactive` property, but I still want the `ListView` to react to clicks, mouse wheel, arrow keys, and have a `ScrollBar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, setting `interactive` to `false` will pretty much immobilize the view.

There is a `keyNavigationEnabled` property which doesn't seem to work at this moment([this critical bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-56578)).

So will need to do a little extra work to get it to work as you want:

```
  MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: ll
    onWheel: ll.flick(0, wheel.angleDelta.y * 5)
  }
  ListView {
    id: ll
    model: 50
    width: 50
    height: 200
    spacing: 5
    focus: true
    interactive: false
    boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
    Keys.onPressed: {
      if (event.key === Qt.Key_Up) flick(0, 500)
      else if (event.key === Qt.Key_Down) flick(0, -500)
    }
    delegate: Rectangle {
      width: 50
      height: 50
      color: "red"
      MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: console.log("clicked")
      }
    }
  }
```

Interactivity is disabled, key navigation is implemented manually, and a background `MouseArea` is used to capture wheel events. Note that you don't have to do anything special to enable clicking on items for a non-interactive view, it works regardless of the view is interactive or not.

Comment: Thanks, this almost gets me there.. The only thing - clicking on the delegate doesn't work and "clicked" never appears in the console. I have Qt 5.8.0 RC.

Comment: @AlexJenter - actually, the problem turned out to be that the wheel capturing mouse area was covering the delegates, if you put it behind the list view it works as expected. See the answer edit.

Comment: This works, thanks. Found another way to solve this: set the propagateComposedEvents property of the wheel-capturing mouse area to "true" . This would help to avoid moving it to the top level and referencing a sibling component.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `DragHandler` with a `target: null` prevents it being dragged with the mouse:

```
import QtQuick 2.12

ListView {
    DragHandler {
        target: null
    }
}
```

If you've got `MouseArea` in the child items of `ListView` / `GridView` then you've got to also patch the `MouseArea`s like that:

```
MouseArea {
    drag.target: Item {}
    DragHandler {}
}
```

Otherwise it somehow propagates and drags the flickable.

Works in Qt 6.6. Maybe someone has an explanation for the logic of this.